# ng-repeat filter with filtered properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list of data that I would like to search through using Angular's typical filtering.

I have an array of objects (one of a few below):

```
{
   vendor: 'Joan\'s Produce',
   date: '2014-04-07',
   total: 888.11,
   note: 'insert note',
   description: 'fresh produce',
   terms: 'Net 10',
   deliverer: 'Joe Truck',
   paid: true
}
```

In the `<thead>` I have input fields to search the date and total fields.

```
<th style="vertical-align:text-top; width:250px;">Date<br />
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateQuery.date" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="dateQuery=''">&times;</button></span>
    </div>
</th>
```

The data in the table has a filter of it's own:

```
<tr ng-repeat="inv in invoices | filter:dateQuery | filter:amountQuery">
    <td>{{inv.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>...
    <td>{{inv.total | currency}}</td>
</tr>
```

The filters within the `ng-repeat` format the date and change the total to a currency.  When I now search those filters, it seems to only search the raw data from which the ng-repeat is pulling from.

*Is there a way to build the input filters in a way that they will search the filtered result?* For instance I have to search the dates with 2014-04-07, and can't add a $ in the total filter.

[**I have build a demo here**](http://www.initrode.co/#/project/y5w4620529)

Comment: You need to pre-filter the raw data in a controller so that `invoices`  contains the data you need to filter by. Or alternatively create a custom filter that strips the `$` from the filter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters on `ng-repeat` will only filter the raw data, this is how `ng-repeat` works. To filter on the output from the filters in your table data cells, I can see two options:

- Attach prefiltered values for date and currency to the objects you are filtering. In order to keep things somewhat DRY, you can use the filters themselves for this purpose, in a controller or elsewhere fitting:

  ```
  object.currencyFlat = $filter('currency')(object.total);
  ```
- Build a custom filter dynamically filtering on the value you present visually in the table:

  ```
  angular.module('myModule').filter('myCurrencyFilter', function($filter) {
      return function(array, text) {
          // Could be more sophisticated
          return array.filter(function(item) {
              return $filter('currency')(item).indexOf(text) !== -1;
          });
      }
  });
  ```

Of these two, the first would be much quicker, as it only formats the object's total as a currency once.

I think neither of these approaches are particularly beautiful. I would love to see a better solution.

Comment: Would you build something else to loop through the `$scope.invoices` to build the 'dry' data?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to attach this data in a for loop or something in the controller, so that your objects have both the `currency` property and `currencyFlat` in `$scope.invoices`. You'd filter on `currencyFlat`, but show `currency` (if they are completely the like, you can also show the pre-formatted (filtered) `currencyFlat` value).

Comment: Your solution was the catalyst to what I ended up doing, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up leveraging Underscore.js to run a `foreach` loop on the scope object

```
_.each($scope.invoices, function (invoice) {
    invoice.filteredDate = $filter('date')(invoice.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    invoice.filteredTotal = $filter('currency')(invoice.total, '$');
});
```

Then referenced the new fields in my HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="inv in invoices | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:dateQuery | filter:totalQuery">
    <td>{{inv.filteredDate}}</td>
    <td>{{inv.vendor}}</td>
    <td>{{inv.filteredTotal}}</td>
    <td>{{inv.terms}}</td>
    <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inv.paid" disabled /></td>
    <td class="center">
        <a ng-click="invoice(inv, $index)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```